# How do the servlet containers identify requests from authenticated users?

Tags: tomcat, authentication, web.xml

If I add an element `<security-constraint>` for some URLs in file web.xml of my web application, my servlet container (say, Tomcat) will protect those URLs and redirect unauthenticated users to a login page.

**But how does the servlet container identify requests from authenticated users?**

Do they expect:

- A cookie in the HTTP request? **Which one?**
- An HTTP header?
- Authentication in the session (session ID?)

In particular, what does Tomcat look for in a request of an authenticated user?

Here is a portion of a web.xml file, as per examples found in common tutorials.
What will the servlet container (and in particular, Tomcat) look for in the request to identify it as coming from an authenticated user?

```
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Restricted GET To Employees</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Restricted Access - Get Only</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/restricted/employee/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Employee</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>MyRealm</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login/loginForm.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/login/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
  <role-name>Employee</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the JSESSIONID cookie is used for the purpose of identifying clients, as defined in the [Servlet Specification (PDF)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY3s-CponVAhUG_4MKHZ3bB9UQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fotn-pub%2Fjcp%2Fservlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec%2Fservlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGUyZPJa59uqkiOPaUuwnDCtDaI-A):

> Session tracking through HTTP cookies is the most used session tracking mechanism
>   and is required to be supported by all servlet containers.
>   **The container sends a cookie to the client. The client will then return the cookie on
>   each subsequent request to the server, unambiguously associating the request with a
>   session. The standard name of the session tracking cookie must be JSESSIONID,
>   which must be supported by all 3.0 compliant containers.** Containers may allow the
>   name of the session tracking cookie to be customized through container specific
>   configuration.

Looking into how authentication happens in Tomcat, after performing a login, the [`org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase#register(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.security.Principal, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#AuthenticatorBase.register%28org.apache.catalina.connector.Request%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Cjava.security.Principal%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) method is called, which caches authentication information, which would be reused by subsequent requests in [`org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase#checkForCachedAuthentication`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#AuthenticatorBase.checkForCachedAuthentication%28org.apache.catalina.connector.Request%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Cboolean%29) to allow authenticated users to proceed, without having to present credentials again.

This means that although a user does not have to be authenticated to have a valid session (identified by their `JSESSIONID` cookie), once they log in their authentication information is cached and bound to their session, so when that user makes new requests, the application server recognizes them as authenticated and allows access to protected resources.